# Select max date that is less than a specific date from other table but maximum among remaining dates - snowflake database

Tags: date, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing a challenge in Selecting the max date from a table that is less than a specific date from another table but is maximum among remaining dates in the snowflake database. The description is a bit confusing, so let me try to explain:

E.g: **Table X**

| ID1 | Date1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 07-17-2022 |
| 2 | 05-22-2022 |

**Table Y**

| ID1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 07-25-2022 |
| 1 | 06-04-2022 |
| 1 | 05-07-2022 |
| 1 | 04-01-2022 |
| 2 | 05-20-2022 |
| 2 | 08-01-2022 |
| 2 | 05-02-2022 |
| 2 | 04-16-2022 |

So I want to achieve the below logic:
**for ID1:**   `DATE2 < DATE1 but DATE2= max(remaining Dates in DATE2 where ID=1)`

**The final result should be**

| ID1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 06-04-2022 |
| 1 | 05-20-2022 |

Note: Date format = `mm-dd-yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve similar result using QUALIFY and DATEDIFF(used for finding the lowest difference between two dates):

```
SELECT Y.ID1, Y.DATE2
FROM  X
INNER JOIN Y
  ON  X.ID1 = Y.ID1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Y.ID1 
                          ORDER BY DATEDIFF('DAY', Y.Date2, X.Date1) DESC) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. This can be done using [correlated subquery](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-subqueries.html#types-of-subqueries) as given below

```
SELECT
    Y.ID1,
    Y.DATE2
FROM
    Y
INNER JOIN X ON
    Y.ID1 = X.ID1
WHERE
    Y.DATE2 = (
    SELECT
        MAX(DATE2)
    FROM
        Y
    WHERE
        Y.ID1 = X.ID1
        AND Y.DATE2 < X.DATE1)
```